# create an empty section(header view) with no cell in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have two entities. user and attributes. user has a one-to-one relationship to attributes and attribute has one-to-many relationship to the user.
i am using FRC(Fetch result controller and want to use 'user' entity as section( header view) and attributes as table view cell. 
I want to be able to add a user section(header view) with no cell.
but as default I get one cell per new section.

here is the code for FRC :

```swift
 lazy var fetchResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<Attribute> = {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Attribute> = Attribute.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Attribute.name), ascending: false)]

        let fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(Attribute.user.name), cacheName: nil)

        fetchResultController.delegate = self

        return fetchResultController
    }()
```

tableView:

```swift
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        guard let sections = fetchResultController.sections else {return 0}
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let section = fetchResultController.sections?[section] else{return 0}
        return section

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ID.TableView.mainPage) as! AttributeCell
        let task = fetchResultController.object(at: indexPath)

        cell.nameLbl.text = task.name

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: you have to add a new section and a validation in `cellForRowAt`function, if you are in the last section only return the cell without data.

Comment: Since you have a one-to-many relationship between attribute and user then attribute must be the section and user the rows for that section. Or did you explain your model incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var numberSections = 0
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    guard let sections = fetchResultController.sections else {
      numberSections = 0
      return 0}
    numberSections = sections + 1
    return sections.count + 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let section = fetchResultController.sections?[section] else{return 0}
    return section + 1

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ID.TableView.mainPage) as! AttributeCell
    let task = fetchResultController.object(at: indexPath)
      //4                //5
    if numberSections - 2 > indexPath.section
    {
       cell.nameLbl.text = task.name
    }
    else
    {
       cell.nameLbl.text = ""
    }

    return cell
}
```

this creates an empty section until the end